# Is there a relationship between spatial/temporal dimensions and the sets in the standard model?

Tags: standard-model

This may be a completely ridiculous question, having very little knowledge about physics at this soft of level, but I'm curious.

According to my superficial understanding of the standard model, there are four sets of particle (three generations of matter, plus the gauge bosons). As laid out in the standard table they seem to be considered to have some equivalency.

There are also usually considered to be four standard dimensions (three spatial and one temporal).

Is there any (speculated or potential) relation between the common sizes (3 + 1) of these sets of fundamental phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we only have two sets of partiles: the fermions and the bosons. The fact that the fermions come in three families does not produce a pattern into which the gauge bosons fit. As a result, the analogy of between space-time and particle, based on the numbers 3+1 does not work.